# unable to access cross domain xml using AJax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain-policy

In my [web applicaiton](http://www.shafinhp.com/) I am trying to access live forex rates provided by [FXCM](https://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML?_=1459088279085) using ajax. but when ever an ajax request is fired it is unable to access the xml response from particular FXCM domain and console shows

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

I know this is due to SOP violations and provided

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

at the top of page but its not working as well.

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML",
                cache: false,
                                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    console.log(xml);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: you can't access data between cross domain using ajax.

Comment: then what should i try?

Comment: to avoid cross domain policy you need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` at server side. Only IE allow cross domain access with lower security. you can try IE to access data over cross domain.

Comment: You can't control CORS headers on your server that way they need to be included in the actual endpoint. Use a proxy on your server to get the data and use that for your ajax. Can use cURL to make request in php to other server